# Electron process object linked to function or global app?

Tags: node.js, process, electron

I want to catch uncaught exceptions in an Electron app. I read that I could use

```
process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
    console.log(err)
}
```

I am wondering if the process object is the general process of the app, or if it is the process of the function it was called in (if it can even be used that way)?

For example if I want to do process.exit or something similar, will it kill the app or shut down the function?

Thanks for your time !

Comment: it's actually node's [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) extended with [several features](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/process/#process) thus it's still global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The `process` object is a `global` that provides information about, and control over, the current Node.js process. As a global, it is always available to Node.js applications without using `require()`.

Yes the process object is the general process of the app.

So if you do `process.exit` it will quit the whole process.

[Process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process)